# What's a secure way to store data from a query in Node & Express to AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making an application with Express and Angular and I want to ask where to keep the results of mongoose queries for Angular to display them.

Here's the idea of my app

1) User logs in, gets authenticated

2) Once authenticated, the server gets the details of the user via mongoose

3) The server sends it to Angular to display it by storing the details in a cookie.

4) Angular accesses the cookie, gets the data inside it and displays it in the template.

My question is, is that the correct way of doing it? Another way I can think of is sending it as a json for Angular to get it ($http.get([url with json data]).then(displayData))

So in short

1) Is it okay or safe in saving the data in a cookie?
2) Are there other ways to do it?

I'm sorry if it comes of as very noobish. I have seen questions regarding sending data from Angular to Node but nothing about Node to Angular.

Note: Using Angular 1.x

Comment: simply res.send(json) in angular get  data and update your variable

Comment: I see. If I wanted to up the security a bit, how could I add additional security to it? Is is safe to just send it as json? Thanks for the quick response btw.

Comment: use JWT token for each request if you are not using sessions

Comment: User authentication and session security is an overly broad topic. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once

Answer (score 0):

To undertake the operations that you have listed you can use *broadly* two approaches, one is **mongoose sessions** with express sessions and another one is to use **JSON Web tokens (JWT)**. And both are *secure way of storing and communicating with the server*. Only difference is that while using sessions we store the *data in the server* and the *client just gets a session ID* through which the server can uniquely identify the user session.But while using JSON web tokens we will have an encrypted token that can be decrypted in the server and then access the needed information

1. So the answer to the first question. Is it safe to store the data in a cookie? **YES!**
2. Is there any other way to do it? **YES** You can use JSON web tokens to communicate with the server. though it takes a bit of a different approach.

Either way both are secure way of commnicating with the server. It all depends on how you want to set the server up. Good luck :)